# How can I pick one child from each family in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

I use SQLite and have a table that contains a list of names, some of them are members of the same family.

```
'-----------------------------------'
| Id | Last Name | First Name | Age |
------------------------------------|
| 1  | Gordon    | James      |  5  |
| 2  | Gordon    | Mike       | 19  |
| 3  | Gordon    | Sara       |  8  |
| 4  | Gordon    | Cludia     | 25  |
| 5  | Sagget    | Bob        | 22  |
| 6  | Saywer    | Tom        |  9  |
| 7  | Saywer    | Jean       | 20  |
| 8  | Finn      | Hucklberry |  8  |
| 9  | Smith     | John       | 18  |
| 10 | Smith     | Sue        | 39  |
'-----------------------------------'
```

I need to select all people who are 18 years of age or older, but picking one member only from each family. The query should pick the youngest person who is older than or equal to 18 years old. For the above example, the query should return the following people:

```
'-----------------------------------'
| Id | Last Name | First Name | Age |
------------------------------------|
| 2  | Gordon    | Mike       | 19  |
| 5  | Sagget    | Bob        | 22  |
| 7  | Saywer    | Jean       | 20  |
| 9  | Smith     | John       | 18  |
'-----------------------------------'
```

Note that Hucklberry Finn was not part of the output since he does not satisfy the condition of 18 years or older, and he has no siblings or relatives :( . Therefore, no 'Finn's are picked.

What is the simplest query to achieve the above result?

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT
    id,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    age
FROM
    people p
WHERE
    age >= 18
    and age < (
      select min(age) from people where age > 18 and last_name = p.last_name
)
```

I feel there must be a more correct and efficient way than my attempt.

Comment: By same family do you mean Last name is same?

Comment: @AmirSaleem Yes

Comment: `select lastName, min(age) as age, any_value(firstName) as firstName, any_value(id) as id from Family p Where age >= 18 group by lastName;` this works

Comment: @AmirSaleem `any_value` does not work in SQLite

Comment: that is why I didn't add as an answer. You can convert in sqlite, this was just to give you an idea

Comment: @AmirSaleem I don't know what the function `any_value()` does. is it an aggregate function?

Comment: yes, it picks any value from the group.

Comment: ... which is why you don't want `ANY_VALUE` or the like, because you don't want to show the youngest persons age along with an older family member's first_name. `ANY_VALUE` picks any value from the group, while you want to pick the values from the youngest person's row.

Comment: What to do with twins, i.e. when there are two youngest persons >= 18 in a family? Show both rows? Pick one arbitrarily? Show one row, with the IDs and first names listed (like 13,17 | 'Miller' | 'Ben, Lilly', 18)? Or something else still?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner in case there are twins with the same age, any one of the twins is fine. Maybe pick the twin with the lowest ID.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with information about how the queries deal with ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach in standard SQL would be to either rank the rows:

```
SELECT id, last_name, first_name, age
FROM
(
  SELECT
    id,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    age,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY last_name ORDER BY age) AS rn
  FROM people p
  WHERE age >= 18
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

or use aggregation

```
SELECT *
FROM people 
WHERE (last_name, age) IN
(
  SELECT
    last_name,
    MAX(age)
  FROM people p
  WHERE age >= 18
  GROUP BY last_name
);
```

or use `WHERE NOT EXISTS <a younger person >= 18 in the same family>`).

```
WITH eighteen_up AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM people 
  WHERE age >= 18
)
SELECT *
FROM eighteen_up p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT null
  FROM eighteen_up younger
  WHERE younger.last_name = p.last_name
  AND younger.age < p.age
);
```

In SQLite, you can usually get this much simpler, as shown in forpas' answer, because of their special treatment of bare columns that other DBMS don't feature. It has its restrictions with ties though that I am explaining below. For this reason it is not a safe option here.

### Update

In the request comments you say that in case there are two (or more) youngest 18+ family members  (think of twins), you want to pick only one of them. My first query does this (you'd have to use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` to get both). My second query does not work as desired then, because it will get both persons. My third query, too, selects both, but can be adjusted to only pick one by replacing `AND younger.age < p.age` by `AND (younger.age < p.age OR (younger.age = p.age AND younger.id < p.id))`.

The SQLite-only query shown in forpas' answer will not be guaranteed to work, because it could pick the ID and the first name from different rows. srinivas st's query works as my second one, i.e. will select both rows, too.

Conclusion: The only approach you should *never* use where ties are possible is the bare-columns approach. Depending on how to deal with ties, pick any of the alternatives.

Comment: I have seen other short straight answers, but yours is more in-depth and inclusive. I learned something new today from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the table for `age >= 18` and agregate:

```
SELECT id,
       last_name,
       first_name,
       MIN(age) AS age
FROM people
WHERE age >= 18
GROUP BY last_name;
```

SQLite [picks the row with the min age from each group](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query).

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/V5LPTypg).

Comment: Good answer generally. This will not work with twins, though. As we'd have a tie (two 18+ persons with the same minimum age), the ID can be picked from one row and the first name from the other. This is where we hit a limitation with the bare-columns approach. It only works guaranteed as long as there are no ties.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner read the doc link. The id and the first_name will be picked from the same row, the row with the min age. What is not guaranteed is which row it will be picked from in case of a tie.

Comment: Quote: If the same minimum or maximum value occurs on two or more rows, then bare values might be selected from any of those rows. The choice is arbitrary. There is no way to predict from which row the bare values will be choosen. The choice might be different for different bare columns within the same query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner https://dbfiddle.uk/nnjpEvdS You may run it as many times as you want. SQLite will always pick the bare columns from the same row (the row with the min rowid).

Comment: Don't argue. The docs say explicitly that the ID may be chosen from another row as the first name, so don't use this approach only because it happens to work for you with your SQLite version with your settings right now.

Answer (score 0):

i think this query helps you to get your desired result

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Last_Name, t1.First_Name, t1.Age
FROM family t1
JOIN (
    SELECT Last_Name, MIN(Age) AS MinAge
    FROM family
    WHERE Age >= 18
    GROUP BY Last_Name
) t2 ON t1.Last_Name = t2.Last_Name AND t1.Age = t2.MinAge
WHERE t1.Age >= 18;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).